# modprobe snd-aloop with AWS EC2 ubuntu 18.04.4 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu

Tried multiple options like executing the below command, but it doesn't work.

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-aloop not found in directory /lib/modules/5.3.0-1017-aws
```

I am new to linux, any solution?

Comment: misse command : sudo apt-get install kmod

Answer (score -2):

Jibri is intented for Ubuntu **16.04**

You must use this specific version, especially if you are new to the linux world. Unlike 16.04, the ubuntu 18.04 use another kernel (5 instead on 4.4) and a sound system which is not yet compatible with Jibri software.

Reinstall Ubuntu **16.04** on your server, and [follow the installation documentation](https://github.com/jitsi/jibri/blob/master/README.md#installing-jibri)

It'll be good then.

Answer (score -3):

Jibri on AWS and getting the below issue. But install Jibri on Ubuntu 16.04 instead of 18.04

> org.jitsi.jibri.capture.ffmpeg.FfmpegCapturer.onFfmpegProcessUpdate() Ffmpeg quit abruptly. Last output line: plug:bsnoop: Input/output error

**Solution:** changing and updating the kernel boot settings from Linux 4.4.0-xxxx-aws to Linux 4.4.0-xxxx-generic and restarting the instance.

I have fixed by the following steps:

> $ grep -A200 submenu  /boot/grub/grub.cfg |grep menuentry

**Output:**

```
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-e6dc6474-8016-46c6-8ab0-0a871bae4cd1' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-1107-aws' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-1107-aws-advanced-e6dc6474-8016-46c6-8ab0-0a871bae4cd1' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-1107-aws (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-1107-aws-recovery-e6dc6474-8016-46c6-8ab0-0a871bae4cd1' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-1106-aws' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-1106-aws-advanced-e6dc6474-8016-46c6-8ab0-0a871bae4cd1' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-1106-aws (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-1106-aws-recovery-e6dc6474-8016-46c6-8ab0-0a871bae4cd1' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-1105-aws' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-1105-aws-advanced-e6dc6474-8016-46c6-8ab0-0a871bae4cd1' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-1105-aws (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-1105-aws-recovery-e6dc6474-8016-46c6-8ab0-0a871bae4cd1' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-179-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-179-generic-advanced-e6dc6474-8016-46c6-8ab0-0a871bae4cd1' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-179-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-179-generic-recovery-e6dc6474-8016-46c6-8ab0-0a871bae4cd1' {
```

menu entry id for Advanced options for Ubuntu is gnulinux-advanced-e6dc6474-8016-46c6-8ab0-0a871bae4cd1
menu entry for Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-179-generic is gnulinux-4.4.0-179-generic-advanced-e6dc6474-8016-46c6-8ab0-0a871bae4cd1

**Edit Grub** and replace GRUB_DEFAULT with above value

> $ nano /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="gnulinux-advanced-e6dc6474-8016-46c6-8ab0-0a871bae4cd1>gnulinux-4.4.0-179-generic-advanced-e6dc6474-8016-46c6-8ab0-0a871bae4cd1"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=tty1 console=ttyS0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

**Update and Reboot**

> $ sudo update-grub
>   $ sudo reboot

After reboot you can test it with uname -a which should give 4.4.0-179-generic

> $ uname -a

Linux 4.4.0-179-generic

After this modprobe snd-aloop should work fine.

Comment: This answer seems discussed here https://github.com/jitsi/jibri/issues/133#issuecomment-634837255 and I tested and worked on ubuntu 18 on azure and aws.

Comment: Doesnt work on Ubuntu 20